# Java - ArrayList for my Node objects does not follow loop condition for excluding duplicates, but default ArrayList of Strings does

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, nodes

I am learning Java and I am currently trying to make a network analysis program.

I have a network class here:

```
    public class Network {

    String name;
    ArrayList<Node> nodes;
    ArrayList<Edge> edges;
    BufferedReader fileObj = null;
    String line;
    ArrayList nn;


    public Network(){
        name = "";
        nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
        edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
        nn = new ArrayList();
    }

    public void addnode(Node nodename) {
        nodes.add(nodename);
    }

    public void addedge(Node node1, Node node2) {
        Edge newedge = new Edge(node1, node2);
        edges.add(newedge);
    }



    public void readfile(String filename) {
        try {
            fileObj = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            new FileInputStream(filename)));

            try {
                while((line = fileObj.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] splitdata = line.split("\\s+");
                    Node node1 = new Node(splitdata[0]);
                    Node node2 = new Node(splitdata[1]);
                    String nn1 = node1.getname();
                    String nn2 = node2.getname();
                    if(!nn.contains(nn1))
                        nn.add(nn1);
                        nodes.add(node1);;
                    if(!nn.contains(nn2))
                        nn.add(nn2);
                        nodes.add(node2);;

                    this.addedge(node1, node2);

                }



                fileObj.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("Reading error " + e);
            }
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
            }

    }
}
```

And I am trying to read a file of node interactions and add each node entry into the Node ArrayList. However, it does not seem to follow the for loop, adding all entries. The nn ArrayList however, correctly exclude duplicates.

I printed the size of each ArrayList, with the following code:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

Network mynetwork = new Network();
mynetwork.readfile("PPInetworkS.txt");

System.out.println(mynetwork.nn.size());
System.out.println(mynetwork.nodes.size());

}   

}
```

This gives a result of 20, and 26, for nn and nodes respectively. Is there something wrong with the for loop, causing the nodes ArrayList to ignore it?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Please do not forget the curly braces:

```
if(!nn.contains(nn1)) {
    nn.add(nn1);
    nodes.add(node1);;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was embarrassing. It works just right now, thanks so much!